# Index out of bounds problem with easyimap

Tags: python

I'm sorry if this has already been answered but I am getting an IndexError: list index out of range with this line:

```
print(unread[item].body)
```

IndexError: list index out of range with this line:

```
print(unread[item].body)
```

I have the following code:

```
import ConfigParser
import easyimap

config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()

path = "settings.ini"

config.read(path)

hostname = config.get("mailserver", "host")
username = config.get("mailserver", "user")
password = config.get("mailserver", "pass")
mailbox  = config.get("mailserver", "mbox")

imapper = easyimap.connect(hostname, username, password, mailbox)

emails = 4
unread = imapper.unseen(emails)

for item in range(emails):
    print(unread[item].body)
```

I've tried rewriteing the for loop to subtract 1 from item then to add 1 to it

Comment: The first obvious question is how many items are in `unread`? Try `print(repr(unread))` just after you define it.

Comment: You probably want `for u in unread: print(u.body)`, but it's impossible to say without more details. Please [edit] and clarify what your question is and what the code is supposed to do. See [mcve] for more details.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `unseen(emails)`, then `emails` states the **limit**
how many **at most** mails should be read.

But the number of mails that have just been read may be **smaller**.
You have no guarantee that just as many mails have been read.
The actual number is the length of the `unread` (list).

So the loop should be:

```
for item in range(len(unread)):
    print(unread[item].body)
```